# Finding the equation of a contour in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, equation, contour

I have a contour plot generated by Matlab. I wish to know the equation of one of the contours drawn by contour function.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks.

P.S. I am new here, so the site didn't let me attach an image file saying I need enough reputation to post images!

Comment: What do you mean by "equation of one of the contours"?

Comment: have you resolved this question?

Answer (score 0):

From `doc contour`:

> ```
> [C,H] = CONTOUR(...) returns contour matrix C as described in CONTOURC
> and a handle H to a contourgroup object.  This handle can be used as
> input to CLABEL.
> ```

And from `contourc`:

> ```
> The contour matrix C is a two row matrix of contour lines. Each
> contiguous drawing segment contains the value of the contour, 
> the number of (x,y) drawing pairs, and the pairs themselves.  
> The segments are appended end-to-end as
>
>     C = [level1 x1 x2 x3 ... level2 x2 x2 x3 ...;
>          pairs1 y1 y2 y3 ... pairs2 y2 y2 y3 ...]
> ```